# How to replace whole word text with hyperlink if there is exact match

Tags: php

I am using the below code to search text in the string and replace with given link but problem is that I only want to replace if there is an exact or whole word match. Below code replace https://example.com with https://example.com but I want to replace if there is exact match it should replace with https://example.com/test/ because this is the complete word and exact match. Any help would be highly appreciated?

```
        $search  = array();
        $replace = array();
        
        $search[]="https://example.com/";
        $search[]="https://example.com/test/";
        $replace[]='<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">' . 'https://example' . '</a>';
        $replace[]='<a href="https://example.com/test/" target="_blank">' . 'https://example/test/' . '</a>';

        $content="this is test content https://example.com/test/";
        
        $content=str_replace($search,$replace,$content);
```

I have tried below code but it does not work

```
    $search[]="/\bhttps://example/\b/";
    $search[]="/\bhttps://example/test/\b/";
    $content=preg_replace($search,$replace,$content);
```

Comment: read about preg_replace() here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Is it possible to re-order your search & replace order? The idea would be to search the "most precise" criteria first: `https://example.com/test/` then the "lest precise" criteria `https://example.com`

Comment: I have solved this using a different approach. I used strtr function.